# メタユーザーの、「参加」の表示順は何によってきまる？

Tags: サポート, メタ

メタでユーザー一覧を表示すると、メインサイトとは違う項目による表示させ方がある様子です。「編集者」タブだったり、「投稿者」タブだったりについては、その順番は期間ごとで表示がきりかえられ、かつ何の順番であるのか割と明確です。

しかし、ひとつ「参加」タブがあって、これは、どの期間の、何の基準で持って並んでいるのかが、いまいち分かりづらいです。メタにおける、このユーザーの「参加」による並び順は、何やって決まっていますか？一見、参加度合いなのかなとも思いますが、それはいったいどう参集されてるんだろう、が疑問です。

Comment: "このサイトにおいて過去 60 日間で最もアクティブなユーザー (投稿数、投票数、コメント数、編集数の総計)。"

Comment: @YukiInoue さん、何だか本文に打ち間違いが見られ、また、第1段落の2文目は途中で主語が変わってしまっているように感じられます。なんとなくご質問の趣旨は分かるのですが、いま少し推敲して下さいませんでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu おっしゃる通りなので推敲いたしました。